# How to make a such animation of UItextView or TTTextView as shown in picture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

an App Shopper implement
As shown in picture:
[image]

there is a table item or a button "Read More..."
when click this button, the button animates to this piece of words' end to show all words up. As shown in picture 2

1. Is it a UITextView?
2. The "Button" is a UIButton or a Table Item?
3. How to implement this animation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar by simply having `UILabel`s and `UITextView`s lined up vertically. For the button I use a transparent `UIButton` of type `UIButtonTypeCustom`. Then I change the frame & text of the labels / textviews (the one with the text, and the ones below it) in an animation block.

There is also a way to do this in a table view. There is an Apple sample code project with section headings that you can click to expand. But the section is still visible, so perhaps this is not the right approach for you.

Comment: Buddy, sorry long time no words back, I may try your way within few months, anyway will update you after tried...  thank you for your reply!